# Nested "if" (AKA "switch") in Smalltalk (Pharo)

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I need to populate the matrix (stored as an array of arrays) with some values. The matrix is a Jacobian for a simple diffusion problem and looks like this:

```
J(1,1) = 1, J(N,N)=0
```

and for `1<n<N`:

```
J(n,n) = -2k/dx^2 - 2*c(n)
J(n,n-1)=J(n,n+1) = k/dx^2
```

the rest of the matrix entries are zeros.

So far I have this monstrosity:

```
(1 to: c size) collect: [ :n |
                (1 to: c size) collect: [ :m |
                    n = 1 | (n = c size)
                        ifTrue: [ m = n ifTrue: [ 1.0 ] ifFalse: [ 0.0 ] ]
                        ifFalse: [ m = n
                            ifTrue: [ -2.0 * k / dx squared - (2.0 * (c at: n)) ]
                            ifFalse: [ m = (n-1) | (m = (n+1))
                                ifTrue: [ k / dx squared ]
                                ifFalse: [ 0.0 ] ] ]
                    ] ]
```

Notice the nested "if-statements" (Smalltalk equivalents). This works. But, is there, perhaps, a more elegant way of doing the same thing? As it stands now, it is rather unreadable.

Comment: For non-toy problems you might want to use a more efficient (sparse) matrix implementation for this.

Comment: @StephanEggermont Surely enough, for more serious task I had to implement a sparse (banded) matrix: speed performance x2 - x3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For readability's sake I would consider sacrificing the extra `O(n)` time and avoid IFs altogether (which just make it even faster...).

```
J(N,N) = 0
J(1,1) = 1
//and for 1<n<N:
J(n,n) = Y(n)
J(n,m-1) = J(n,m+1) = X
```

What this tells me is that the whole matrix looks something like this

```
( 1 X 0 0 0 )
( X Y X 0 0 )
( 0 X Y X 0 )
( 0 0 X Y X )
( 0 0 0 X 0 )
```

Which means that I can create the whole matrix with just zeros, and then change the diagonal and neighboring diagonals.

```
jNM := [ k / dx squared ].
jNN := [ :n | -2.0 * k / dx squared - (2.0 * (c at: n)) ].

n := c size.
m := Matrix
    new: n 
    tabulate: [:i :j | 0 ].
(1 to: n - 1) do: [ :i |
    m at: i at: i put: (jNN value: i).
    m at: i + 1 at: i put: jnM value.
    m at: i at: i + 1 put: jnM value.
].
m at: 1 at: 1 put: 1.
```

Note: I'm not familiar with the math behind this but the value for `J(n,m-1)` seems like a constant to me.

Note 2: I'm putting the values at `i + 1` indexes, because I am starting at position `1;1`, but you can start from the opposite direction and have `i-1`.

Comment: Yes, I should have thought about just going along the diagonal in the first place! As for your question: `J(n,n-1)` is constant here indeed. But in general, it can be more complicated.

Answer (score 6):

```
n := c size.
Matrix
  new: n
  tabulate: [:i :j | self jacobianAtRow: i column: j]
```

where

```
jacobianAtRow: i column: j
  n := c size.
  (i = 1 or: [i = n]) ifTrue: [^j = i ifTrue: [1.0] ifFalse [0.0]].
  j = i ifTrue: [^-2.0 * k / dx squared - (2.0 * (c at: i))].
  (j = (i - 1) or: [j = (i + 1)]) ifTrue: [^k / dx squared].
  ^0.0
```

Basically, the general idea is this: whenever you find nested ifs, factor out that piece of code to a method by itself and transform the nesting into a cases-like enumeration that returns a value at every possibility.

Comment: I think this approach will be better in general, but this matrix population is just for the test case. So, I will go with another answer, which is better for my specific case.

Comment: I liked @Peter's solution too and I think that both of us had the intention of making you aware of the `new:tabulate:` method (which I call `fromBlock:dimension:` instead)

Comment: Unfortunately, the matrix I'm using doesn't have this method. Maybe I shouldn't be using it and use standard `Matrix` class (or add `new:tabulate:` to it), but that is a different issue :)

Comment: @mobiuseng What I meant is that the `new:tabulate:` method would, to my preference, be more expressive if it had the selector `fromBlock:dimension:`. Both methods do the same and only differ in their selectors (and the order of the arguments.)